# Keep a label tag with date material ui

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

[image: SHOW IMAGE]

How to keep a label position like T.M.T SKEP, if the default value is not set? I am using material UI.

```
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

<TextField
  fullWidth
  label="T.M.T"
  id="tmt"
  name="tmt"
  type="date"
  value=""
  variant="outlined"
 />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this property in the TextField.

```
 InputLabelProps={{
          shrink: true
        }}
```

---

```
 <TextField
        fullWidth
        label="T.M.T"
        id="tmt"
        name="tmt"
        type="date"
        value=""
        variant="outlined"
        InputLabelProps={{
          shrink: true
        }}
      />
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-swew3?file=/demo.js